# Если работать с Python, зачем знания CSS, HTML?

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Я начинающий в разработке человек, поэтому сильно не ругайте.

Изучаю прекрасный язык Python, до этого обрел базовые знания С++. Сам язык Python, особенно после С++, очень нравится, ибо всё просто и красиво, а так же понятно. Но вот смотрел вакансии от IT-компаний и в 90% их пишут, что помимо Python, нужно знать: HTML, CSS, JS, XML и Django\Flesk с SQL! То, что SQL и Django знать надо - это вроде понятно, так как "сиквел" по-любому нужен, а Django - это фреймворк для построения web-приложений и с помощью Python пишется серверная часть.
То есть получается если разработчик устраивается в такую компанию, он пишет серверную часть и верстку?
  **Просто мне не нравится работать с каскадными стилями и языками разметки (в общем верстка)**

Answer (score 3):

В 90% случаев вы же ещё будете тех задание писать, а также освоите глажку, готовку и вышивание крестиком...
Если связаны с Web-разработкой, то никуда от знания HTML+CSS+JS не деться. Не факт, что знания придётся активно применять на практике, но иметь представление очень и очень надо.

В крупных организациях, возможно, и есть узкие специалисты, которые только и знай себе, что CSS целыми днями разгребают, но в остальных случаях универсальность человека скорее плюс.

Comment: подтверждаю вышесказанное.
да и в той же джанге, чтобы минимально темплейт сделать, нужны базовые знания хтмл, даже при учете, что верстать будет другой человек.

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что в большинстве случаев когда в вакансии пишут Python подразумевают web разработку. Если вы планируете писать сайты, то без знания HTML и CSS вы никуда не уйдете, так же вам следует изучить JS (в частности jQuery, Ajax).

Если у вас не будет никаких знаний о том как это работает - это все равно что человек за рулем, не знающий правил дорожного движения. Попав в ДТП он будет недоумевать почему так произошло.

Поэтому не ленитесь и прочитайте хотя бы htmlbook.

Если же вы интересуетесь десктопными приложениями - ищите соответствующие вакансии, и знайте что если в вакансии HTML - это не то, что вы ищите.

Answer (score 2):

В конечном счете веб-программы на Питоне (а также на PHP, Ruby, Java, C++, asm) выдают код страниц на HTML, CSS и JS (с вариантами). Так что очевидно, что от знаний этих технологий веб-программисту не уйти, если он хочет стать настоящим специалистом.

Answer (score 1):

Ну так и написано, что нужно **знать**, а не разрабатывать. Вы должны будете знать данную область и в случае чего в работе с этой областью разобраться и поучаствовать. Это нормально.

Answer (score 1):

"но вот смотрел вакансии от IT-компаний и в 90% их пишут что по мимо Python нужно знать : HTML, CSS, JS, XML и Django\Flesk с SQL ! То что SQL и Django знать надо это вроде понятно, так как "сиквел" полюбому нужен, а Django это фреймворк для построения web-приложений и с помощью Python пишеться серверная часть. То есть получаеться если разработчик устраиваеться в такую компанию он пишет серверную часть и верстку ?"

Это означает, что компания занимается не чем иным, как ВЕБ-РАЗРАБОТКОЙ. А веб-разработчику, даже если он пишет преимущественно на Питоне, в своей работе ПОСТОЯННО приходится сталкиваться с HTML.

В большой компании под HTML-верстку и JavaScript-программирование есть отдельно выделенные люди. В небольшой - очень даже может быть, что придется самому. Это лучше сразу уточнить при приеме на работу.

Но даже если столь ненавистной Вам версткой будут заниматься другие люди, то, даже, если Вы  занимаетесь чисто Питоном, то взаимодействие с HTLM-кодом будет довольно плотным и постоянным. Изо-дня в день. И мелочи в верстке будет править самостоятельно наверняка и небольшие кусочки HTML будете генерировать и отлаживать самостоятельно наверняка.

Поэтому если Вам интересен Питон, но Вы категорически не приемлите HTML, то Вам не повезло. Питон без HTML встречается крайне редко.

Comment: @Softa

      Питон без HTML встречается крайне редко.

Как-то я не уверен в правильности этого утверждения. Кроме веб-разработок питон ещё много где ползает.